# A second operation started on this context... It happens only when I make 2 requests at the same time (2 tabs opening)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container

I have a website built in MVC 5, with Entity Framework 6 and Unity for Dependency Injection.

In the DI container I've registered the DbContext as Transient:

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

Then I have service classes that get the DbContext injected. It all works fine, but I get the "second operation started..." when I make 2 requests at the same time (restoring chrome tabs), or multiple AJAX calls to web api. Otherwise, it all works fine. It's really frustrating to debug this error, not sure how to approach it. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you want `PerRequestLifetimeManager` instead.

Comment: Take a look at your object graph.  If any class is registered as container controlled (singleton) then all dependencies will effectively be singletons as well.

Comment: The problem seemed to be that I was accessing to some items that were lazy loaded after they were returned from my service layer. What I've done is wrap all queries with using db = dbcontext pool. And I have a class to manage a pool of db contexts. It seems to have fixed the problem.